# Functor on category with small limits

Tags: category-theory

Let $F: \mathbb{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ be a functor and assume that $\mathbb{A}$ has small limits. Show that for every $B \in \mathbb{B}$ the comma category $B \downarrow F$ has small limits too.

I am struggling to prove this supposedly easy exercise. My idea is to prove the existence of small limits in $B \downarrow F$ by showing that the category has equalizers and small products. However, this approach leads to some unexpected problems.

Let me explain this in greater detail. The category $B \downarrow F$ has as objects pairs $(\alpha, I)$ such that $\alpha: B \rightarrow F(I)$ is a morphism in $\mathbb{B}$. A morphism from $(\alpha, I)$ to $(\beta, J)$ is a map $f \in \mathbb{A}(I, J)$ such that $F(f) \circ \alpha = \beta$. Please correct me if there is any mistake so far.

In order to prove that $B \downarrow F$ has equalizers, I consider two elements $(X, \alpha)$ and $(Y, \beta)$ in the comma category together with two morphisms $f_1, f_2: Y \rightarrow X$ mapping $(\beta, Y)$ to $(\alpha, X)$. Then there must be some $(\gamma, E) \in B \downarrow F$ and some $e: E \rightarrow Y$ with the following two properties:

(1) $F(f_1) \circ F(e) = F(f_2) \circ F(e)$

(2) For every $(\delta, I) \in B \downarrow F$ and every morpism $g: I \rightarrow J$ mapping $(\delta, I)$ to $(\beta, Y)$ with $f_1 \circ g = f_2 \circ g$ there exists a unique $h: I \rightarrow E$ such that $f_1 \circ g = f_1 \circ e \circ h$.

The situation is summarized in the following diagram. [image]

Now, my idea is to take the equalizer $e: E \rightarrow Y$ of $f_1, f_2$ in $\mathbb{A}$ and translate this into some element $(\gamma, E) \in B \downarrow F$ such that $e$ maps $(\gamma, E)$ to $(\beta, Y)$. However, to do that I need the existence of some $\gamma: B \rightarrow F(E)$ such that $F(e) \circ \gamma = \beta$ and I do not know how to ensure that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The comma category $(B \downarrow F)$ has a projection to $\mathcal{A}$. Show that this projection creates limits.

Comment: I am relatively new to category theory, therefore excuse the question: What do you mean with projection to $\mathcal{A}$? (I suppose $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{A}$)

Comment: The functor that sends the pair $(\alpha, I)$ to $I$.

Comment: Your problem in your last paragraph is that you forgot that maps in $B\downarrow F$ are *maps in $A$*, not in $B$. In particular, the commutativity of the diagram tells you that $f_1\circ g = f_2\circ g$, not only after applying $F$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Thanks, that helps a lot